# How to include ancestor branch of a node selected via xpath parameter in output of XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

After trying for over 8 hours I am hoping someone can help me with this:

Given the following (simplified) XML for a book:

```
<book>
    <section name="A">
        <chapter name="I">
            <paragraph name="1"/>
            <paragraph name="2"/>
        </chapter>
        <chapter name="II">
            <paragraph name="1"/>          
        </chapter>
    </section>
    <section name="B">
        <chapter name="III"/>
        <chapter name="IV"/>   
    </section>
</book>
```

I am able to extract any part (section, chapter or paragraph) of the book XML based on a given parameter with the following XSL:

```
<xsl:param name="subSelectionXPath" required="yes" as="node()"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$subSelectionXPath"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- output node with all children -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

and the parameter **$subSelectionXPath** with a value like

```
doc(filename)//chapter[@name='II']
```

resulting in output:

```
<chapter name="II">
    <paragraph name="1"/>          
</chapter>
```

what I want to achieve in addition is to have the the selected XML fragment enclosed by the ancestor XML branch, i.e.:

```
<book>
    <section name="A">
        <chapter name="II">
            <paragraph name="1"/>          
        </chapter>
    </section>    
</book>
```

I imagine (and tried) traversing the XML tree and testing whether the current node is an ancestor, something like (pseudo code):

```
<xsl:if test="node() in $subSelectionXPath/ancestor::node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:if>
```

I also experimented with xsl:key but I am afraid my knowledge of XSLT is running to an end here. Any thoughts?

Comment: So, given an input element, you want copy back its ancestors and output the element with the ancestors, without any siblings, am I right?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: I also added a detailed explanation.

Comment: I also added a similar XSLT 1.0 solution using the Kayessian formula for the intersection of two nodesets.

Comment: Interestingly, the draft XSLT 3.0 specification defines a function snapshot() that does essentially what you are looking for. I found that coding it in XSLT was surprisingly difficult, though many of the difficulties were caused by an added twist in the requirement, namely that the result of the function should be the node in the output tree corresponding to the originally selected node in the input tree.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Interesting that XSLT 3.0 will have a function that does exactly this. I owe you guys a beer!

Comment: Much more interesting is that you have here three pretty good answers and you have not accepted one yet. :)

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't even aware you could/should do that on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is evident from your code that you are using XSLT 2.0.

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="subSelectionXPath"
  as="node()" select="//chapter[@name='II']"
  />

 <xsl:template match="*[descendant::node() intersect $subSelectionXPath]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[. intersect $subSelectionXPath]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<book>
    <section name="A">
        <chapter name="I">
            <paragraph name="1"/>
            <paragraph name="2"/>
        </chapter>
        <chapter name="II">
            <paragraph name="1"/>
        </chapter>
    </section>
    <section name="B">
        <chapter name="III"/>
        <chapter name="IV"/>
    </section>
</book>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<book>
   <section name="A">
      <chapter name="II">
         <paragraph name="1"/>
      </chapter>
   </section>
</book>
```

**Explanation**: We have just two templates:

1. A template that matches any element whose descendents have non-empty intersection with the `$subSelectionXPath` node-set. Here we "shallow-copy" the element and apply templates to its children elements.
2. A template that matches elements that belong to the `$subSelectionXPath` node-set. Here we copy the whole subtree rooted at that element.
3. Do note the use of the XPath 2.0 `intersect` operator.
4. *No* explicit recursion.

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="subSelectionXPath"
  select="//chapter[@name='II']"
  />

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test=
   "descendant::node()
        [count(.|$subSelectionXPath)
        =
         count($subSelectionXPath)
        ]
   ">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:when>

   <xsl:when test=
   "count(.|$subSelectionXPath)
   =
    count($subSelectionXPath)
   ">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the same XML document (shown already above), the same wanted and correct result is produced**:

```
<book>
   <section name="A">
      <chapter name="II">
         <paragraph name="1"/>
      </chapter>
   </section>
</book>
```

**Explanation**: This is essentially the XSLT 2.0 solution in which the XPath 2.0 `intersect` operator is translated to XPath 1.0 using the well-known Kayessian (for @Michael Kay) formula for intersection of two nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

Comment: @empo: Your appreciation is something that I value very high. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think the way to do what you're trying to accomplish is with a recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="copyElementsOnAncestorAxis">
      <xsl:with-param name="nodeList"
                      select="//chapter[@name='I']/ancestor-or-self::*"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="copyElementsOnAncestorAxis">
    <xsl:param name="nodeList"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if the context node is the last node in the list, copy it entirely -->
      <xsl:when test=". = $nodeList[count($nodeList)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- otherwise, just copy the element, its attributes, and any child element that 
           is also in the node list -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="*[. = $nodeList]">
            <xsl:call-template name="copyElementsOnAncestorAxis">
              <xsl:with-param name="nodeList"
                              select="$nodeList"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which, when applied to the XML you provided, produces this:

```
<book>
  <section name="A">
    <chapter name="I">
      <paragraph name="1" />
      <paragraph name="2" />
    </chapter>
  </section>
</book>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another recursion-based solution. Explanation:

- first apply-templates to the last ancestor
- then, if ancestor of the current parameter node copy it and if parent copy the node and end, otherwise recurse

Here the transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="subSelectionXPath" 
        select="document('test_input2.xml')//chapter[@name='II']"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="$subSelectionXPath/ancestor::*[position()=last()]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:choose>

            <xsl:when test="$subSelectionXPath/ancestor::*
                [generate-id() = generate-id(current())]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="generate-id(.)=
                            generate-id($subSelectionXPath/ancestor::*[1])">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$subSelectionXPath"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input provided in the question, assuming the input parameter value the same in the question, produces:

```
<book>
   <section name="A">
      <chapter name="II">
         <paragraph name="1"/>
      </chapter>
   </section>
</book>
```

Comment: Sorry for the many editings, but the formatting is driving me crazy :)

Comment: Interestingly it is this solution that works for me. For reasons of clearity I had simplified the example, but in my actual code the $subSelectionXPath parameter starts with doc(...) as well as I supply it from the command line. This didn't work out Dimitre's code, but does work in Empo's.

Comment: @Brunsaim: All you need is substitute in my code the definition of `$subSelectionXpath` with your definition -- I avoid using `doc()` or `document()` in my answers when the essence wouldn't change at all.